# ("Solved")LFS QT4 (4.8.7) Install Fails at "dialogs/qprintdialog_unix.cpp"

Tags: qt, qt4, kde-plasma, qt4.8, linux-from-scratch

I have been following the blfs guide on KDE and I needed QT4 for one of the dependencies of "KDE-Baseapps". Running:

```
./configure -prefix $QT4PREFIX \
-sysconfdir /etc/xdg \
-confirm-license \
-opensource \
-release \
-dbus-linked \
-system-sqlite \
-no-phonon \
-no-phonon-backend \
-no-webkit \
-no-openvg \
-nomake demos \
-nomake examples \
-optimized-qmake \
-no-openssl &&

make
```

After some time of compiling I get these errors: https://pastebin.com/jrs9w2Ei

Since it involved printing I assumed it was CUPS, but when I used the parameter "--no-cups" I got the same output.

EDIT: My LFS version is 9.1 but the BLFS book was 7.9 because that is the latest I can find on qt4

Comment: What version is your B/LFS system (`cat /etc/lfs-release`)? What BLFS book version are you referencing to build KDE? Btw, `--no-cups` should be `-no-cups`, but I'm not convinced that cups is your problem.

Comment: My LFS version is 9.1 but the BLFS book was 7.9 because that is the latest I can find on qt4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KDE-Baseapps was for KDE4 while I have KDE5. What I needed from KDE-Baseapps was a seperate package easily installed from:

https://download.kde.org/stable/release-service/20.04.1/src/